# MSSQL Stored Proc Parameter error: The data types numeric and nvarchar are incompatible in the percentile_cont operator

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've hit a strange problem yesterday when I programmed a seemingly harmless stored procedure. This is the relevant snippet of the code:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProc]
   @Attr1 NVARCHAR(50)      = '[Col]'
   @Calc numeric(3,2)       = 0.1
   @JobID NVARCHAR(15)      = '1'

   AS
   BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select distinct @JobID,

    PERCENTILE_CONT(@Calc)
            within group (order by @Attr1)
            over(partition by @JobID) as S_1_10
from table
where JobID = 1
```

The stored procedure stops with error 'The data types numeric and nvarchar are incompatible in the percentile_cont operator.' at 'over(partition by @JobID) as S_1_10'. I already know that the problem lies in @Attr1. If I exchange this with the name [Col] of the column, it works fine. It seems as if a variable is not allowed here, but that does not make any sense to me. I've got another stored procedure in which i have the exactly same scenario, but I construct it as a string and execute it with sp_executesql.

I'm using MSSQL 2014. Thank you for any idea in advance!

Comment: This isn't allowed in any database, not just SQL Server. You *can't* pass a table or column name as a string name, any more than you can pass the *name* of an integer parameter in C# to a function that expects an integer value. And that other stored procedure 1) is completely different as it already has a concrete name once constructed 2) is a SQL Injection bug.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you need:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProc]
   @Attr1 NVARCHAR(50)      = '[Col]'
   @Calc numeric(3,2)       = 0.1
   @JobID NVARCHAR(15)      = '1'

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(200)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT JobID,  PERCENTILE_CONT('+@Calc+') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY '+@Attr1+') OVER(PARTITION BY JobID) AS S_1_10 FROM TABLE WHERE JobID = @JobID'

    SET @params = '@JobID NVARCHAR(15)'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @params, @JobID=@JobID
END
```

You have to use dynamic SQL, while most of the time it's not good idea - due to potential of code injection, you might want to minimize risk by using [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) rather than [EXEC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I should have come on that myself.